# How to solve "Could not import 'todo.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. AttributeError: module 'graphene' has no attribute 'string'."?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I create the Django graphene project. Suddenly I get an error **Could not import 'todo.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. AttributeError: module 'graphene' has no attribute 'string'.** But I don't find how to solve it.

My schema structure is:
**todo/schema/schema**

**seting.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # third party app
    'graphene_django',
    'django_filters',
]

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'todo.schema.schema'
}
```

**main urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('graphql/', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
]
```

**schema.py:**

```
class Query(TodoQuery, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


class Mutation(Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

**app schema.py:**

```
# declar todo model field
class TodoType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TodoList
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'date', 'text')


# declar user model filed
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User


# todo list query
class TodoQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    todoList = DjangoListField(TodoType)

    def resolve_todoList(root, info):
        return TodoList.objects.filter(userId=2)


# create todo
class TodoCreate(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        title = graphene.String(Required=True)
        text = graphene.string(Required=True)

    todo = graphene.Field(TodoType)

    def mutate(root, info, title, text):
        # userId = info.context.user
        user = User.objects.get(id=2)
        todo = TodoList(userId=user, title=title, text=text)
        todo.save()
        return TodoCreate(todo=todo)


# todo mutation
class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    createTodo = TodoCreate.Field()
```

What I have missed? Or maybe I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo at `text = graphene.string(Required=True)`. It also says in the error that graphene doesn't have an attribute string. It's case sensitive and should be `text = graphene.String(Required=True)` You can use a linter for your editor so you can catch minor stuff like this in the future.